# Normal subgroups of the semidihedral group of order 16?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are the normal subgroups of the semidihedral group of order 16? For such a fundamental result, there doesn't seem to be a reference to this online...

The semidihedral group of order 16 is given by $\langle \sigma, \tau\rangle$, where $\sigma^8 = \tau^2 = e$ and $\sigma\tau = \tau\sigma^3$.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\sigma^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 normal subgroups, namely, the trivial subgroup, $\langle\sigma^4\rangle$, $\langle\sigma^4, \tau\rangle$, $\langle\sigma^2\rangle$, $\langle\sigma^2, \tau\rangle$, and $\langle\sigma\rangle$.

Comment: Can you expand how did you derive this?

Comment: Maybe one can turn to the character table of this group to find out all normal subgroups: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_semidihedral_group:SD16  . But getting its character table is not an easy job.

Answer (score 0):

[This page has a nice subgroup tree with details on which relation is normal](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/SD16.html)

In your notation, the normal sugroups are:

$\{e,\sigma^2,\sigma^4,\sigma^6,\sigma\tau,\sigma^3\tau,\sigma^5\tau,\sigma^7\tau\}\cong Q_8$, the quaternian group

$\{e,\sigma^2,\sigma^4,\sigma^6,\tau,\sigma^2\tau,\sigma^4\tau,\sigma^6\tau\}\cong D_4$, the dihedral group (sometimes named $D_8)$

$\{e,\sigma,\ldots,\sigma^7\}\cong C_8$, the cyclic group

Other than the two normal cyclic subgroups $C_2 \subset C_4 \subset C_8$, none of the other nontrivial subgroups are normal in $SD_{16}$. You can check that $Q_8$ and $D_4$ have no normal subgroups of themselves - they have copies of $C_4$, $C_2$, and the Klein $4$ group $C_2^2$, but those copies are not normal. If you count $\langle e \rangle$ and $SD_{16}$ there are then seven altogether in $SD_{16}$.